# How to display author name instead of author ID while working with WordPress REST API JSON data in Android Java

Tags: android, json, wordpress

I'm quite new to Android, I'm developing an App that pulls data from WordPress posts in form of JSON data, using the default WordPress REST API that comes with WordPress installation. I'm also using Android Volley package for the HTTP requests. I have managed to display Featured image, Title and the Date of the post. However, when I try to display the name of the Author I get the ID (in my case the ID is 1) - In WordPress JSON data the Author has an ID of 1. I would like to display the full name of the Author instead of ID. Please help.

[image: Featured Image, Post Title, Date and Author ID are displayed]

Link to JSON Data (https://www.eazypropertylist.co.ke/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=10)
The Code in my Java Class:

```
public class Post {
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private String date;
    private String feature_image;
    private String author;


    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
}
```

Code in my Adapter

```
public PostsAdapter(List<Post> allPosts) {
        this.allPosts = allPosts;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_view,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.postTitle.setText(allPosts.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.postDate.setText(allPosts.get(position).getDate());
        holder.postAuthor.setText(allPosts.get(position).getAuthor());
        Picasso.get().load(allPosts.get(position).getFeature_image()).into(holder.postImage);



        // handle the click on post

        holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),Details.class);
                i.putExtra("title",allPosts.get(position).getTitle());
                i.putExtra("date",allPosts.get(position).getDate());
                i.putExtra("content",allPosts.get(position).getContent());
                v.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return allPosts.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView postImage;
        TextView postTitle;
        TextView postDate;
        TextView postAuthor;
        View view;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view = itemView;
            postImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
            postTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            postDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_date);
            postAuthor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_author);
        }
    }
}
```

In Main Activity Java

```
public void extractPosts(String URL){
        // use volley to extract the data

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.toString());
                for(int i = 0; i < response.length();i++){

                    try {
                        Post p = new Post();

                        JSONObject jsonObjectData = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        // extract the date
                        p.setDate(jsonObjectData.getString("date"));


                        // extract the title
                        JSONObject titleObject = jsonObjectData.getJSONObject("title");
                        p.setTitle(titleObject.getString("rendered"));

                        // extract the content
                        JSONObject contentObject = jsonObjectData.getJSONObject("content");
                        p.setContent(contentObject.getString("rendered"));

                        //extract the excerpt
                        JSONObject excerptObject = jsonObjectData.getJSONObject("excerpt");
                        p.setExcerpt(excerptObject.getString("rendered"));

                        // extract feature image
                        p.setFeature_image(jsonObjectData.getString("jetpack_featured_media_url"));

                        // extract the author
                        p.setAuthor(jsonObjectData.getString("author"));


                        posts.add(p);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        queue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: I think you'll have to get the Author name via the `users` endpoint, it is : https://www.eazypropertylist.co.ke/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1 where `1` is the Id which returns further information.

Comment: @DarShan Thanks for your response, I wanted to find a way to use JSON Arrays and Objects to do it, similar to what I have done with Title and Date.

Comment: If you check the response of the url: https://www.eazypropertylist.co.ke/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1, you'll see the response is in Json, so you can simply get the `name` object, & for future reference, you could just save the id & name in shared preference so that you do not have to fetch it every-time

Comment: @DarShan, I know that endpoint, what I wanted is to dynamically pull each Author related to a post, same way I'm dynamically displaying Title, Date and Featured Image. See my Java code in Main Activity above.